# Implementing And and OR methods in Bifunctions using Generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-8

I am trying to implement 'and'  and 'or' methods in Bifunction the way we have in Predicates.

So, my bifunction functional interface has one abstract method - which takes two objects as arguments and returns a list .

I tried this:

```
public interface TriFunctionInterface<T, U, R> {
    List<R> applyFilter(T t, U u, List<R> r);
    default TriFunctionInterface or(TriFunctionInterface other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (T t, U u, List<R> r) -> {
            List<R> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<R> filteredObjects1 = applyFilter(t, u, r);
            List<R> filteredObjects2 = other.applyFilter(t, u, r);
            finalList.addAll(filteredObjects1);
            finalList.addAll(filteredObjects2);
            return finalList;
       };
    }
}
```

But it seems to be give me an error at this line: 'return (T t, U u, List r) -> {'

Comment: So your question basically is "how do I create alist containing the elements that exist in two other lists", right? What have you tried? What could be the algorithm to do that?

Comment: @JBNizet I have added in question, what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems to be give me an error

It **does** give an error, which says:

```
Error:(11, 16) java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression.
```

This error is caused by the fact that your method uses raw types instead of proper generic types. It should be

```
default TriFunctionInterface<T, U, R> or(TriFunctionInterface<T, U, R> other)
```

Comment: Okay, So that means  I cant use list in lambda arguments? Then is there a way to treat R as a list. because I am using list methods in my 'or' method on R.

Comment: Why couldn't you. Just replace your method declaration (using raw types) by mine (not using raw types), and your code will compile. You just have to copy and paste.

Comment: Yes, it does! I guess I'll spend more time to understand the concepts behind this. Thank you!